# IE8 breaking the function : Expected identifier, string or number

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
success: function(html){
    var halfh = html.height;
    $('#contact_'+id).show();
    $('#contact_'+id).css({'width':'90%'}).animate({
        opacity: '0.6',
        height: halfh
    }, 500 ,'linear').animate({
        opacity: '1',
    },500,'linear',function(){  <--- Error on this line
        $(this).html(html.content)
    });
```

Note: I changed it all to Double quote like:

```
    opacity: "0.6",
    height: halfh
}, 500 ,"linear").animate({
    opacity:"1",
},500,"linear",function(){
```

BUT still same error :(

Please help.
Regards

Comment: remove the comma after "opacity:"1",

Comment: Yes.. it worked.. you should have posted as answer.. so that i could have selected you and given you +1 :)

Comment: soderslatt is correct, it's that comma (Firefox doesn't usually complain about extra commas but IE does and throws an error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in my previous comment. There is a trailing comma.

```
opacity:"0.6",
        height: halfh
      }, 500 ,"linear").animate({
         opacity:"1"
      },500,"linear",function(){
```

Answer (score 2):

as @soderslatt wrote in the comment, there is a wrong comma. removed it and optimized your code a bit.

```
success: function(html){
    $('#contact_' + id).show().css({'width': '90%'}).animate({
            opacity: 0.6,
            height: html.height
          }, 500, 'linear').animate({
             opacity: 1
          }, 500, 'linear', function() {
              $(this).html(html.content);
          });
}
```

Comment: Your code is good.. thank you.. but as i promised.. i selected the answer of @soderslatt .. hope you wont mind it.. i given +1 to your answer also :)

Comment: sure, no problem... he was faster with his comment. first come, first served. thx for the +1

Answer (score 1):

```
}, 500 ,'linear').animate({
   opacity:'1',  <---  Remove this comma
},500,'linear',function(){
```